# Mapping Models/DB to an external API, what is recommended design?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, activerecord

What would be the best way to handle mapping Laravel models to an external API?

The external API has entities such as:

- user
- posts
- comments

On my local database, I also have similar entities:

- user
- posts
- comments

I need to store certain info in my database whenever modifying them on the external API, basically mapping the API to the database.

What is the recommended approach or design pattern for this?

What I have tried:

**1- Directly in the model**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function createPost(array $data, array $attributes)
    {
       $postId = Http::post('.../post', $data)->json('data.postId');

        $this->posts()->create(array_merge([
            'post_id' => $postId,
        ], $attributes));
    }
}

///

$user->createPost([
  'title' => 'foo',
  'content' => 'bar'
], [
  'publish_date' => now()
])
```

I don't really like calling APIs inside the model, and there are problems with naming conflicts, such as updating a post, what do I call the method in the Post Model, `$post->updatePost()`? it does not feel right.

**2 -Using a service:**

```php
class UserService
{

    public function __construct(
        private User $user
    ) {
    }

    public function createPost(array $data, array $attributes = [])
    {
       $postId = Http::post('.../post', $data)->json('data.postId');

        $this->user->posts()->create(array_merge([
            'post_id' => $postId,
        ], $attributes));
    }
}

///

$userService = new UserService($user);

$userService->createPost([
  'title' => 'foo',
  'content' => 'bar'
], [
  'publish_date' => now()
])
```

The service approach feels cleaner, but I wonder if there is any other design pattern I could follow for the above approach that is better/cleaner.

Has anyone implemented something similar, if yes, how did you do it? And did you call your wrapper class a service, or is it rather a wrapper/adapter/decorator?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is data sync via code. Mysql replicas are doing just that in aws for example. In that case your local would be the replica (read) and the api db would be the write db. It would be better than you syncing data via api calls...

But anyway. If you really want or must go this path then you can use observers if all your create, update and delete are done NOT via MASS queries (RESTful apis don't have mass queries for these anyway).

As a side note, you can check this out also: [Is there a way to handle filtering and aggregations for any table in laravel or lumen 8, 9, 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014956/is-there-a-way-to-handle-filtering-and-aggregations-for-any-table-in-laravel-or)